# How can I test if an objects property is below 0 without changing its value C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

This is the start of a very simple banking application.

I have abstract base class which this class inherits from.

```
    public class CheckingAccount : AccountBase
    {
        public override bool Withdraw(float withdrawAmount)
        {
            if ((Balance -= withdrawAmount) < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                Balance -= withdrawAmount;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The withdraw function has an if statement which checks if the balance minus the withdraw amount would be less than 0. If it is less than 0 it returns false and does not do the operation. If it is more than 0 then it moves to the else block and does the operation and returns true.

When I test this in the main function, like this:

```
CheckingAccount cAccount = new CheckingAccount();

cAccount.Deposit(300);

cAccount.Withdraw(500);

Console.WriteLine(cAccount.Balance.ToString());
```

The final output is still -200. When I place breakpoints in the code, I see that it is going through the correct path with it not directly changing the Balance property as it just returns false however, the comparison in the if statement is still changing the actual property. i know that classes are reference types however I do not know how to pass this by value instead as I just want to check if it would be less than 0 and not actually change to stored value in the property.

I tried to do a simple comparison however this comparison ended up actually changing the property. I've tried changing around things here but nothing's really working. I'm new to programming still so this might be a silly question but I can't find any answers.

Comment: Just use `if ((Balance - withdrawAmount) < 0) ... `. Why modify the variable if you don't want to modify it? Even worse, you now subtract twice...! Or use this alternative: `if (Balance < withdrawAmount) ... `

Comment: What @PeterB said. The way you have it now, even if balance is good, you subtract twice.

Comment: You should learn how to write the simple code, fancy syntax is never good . Why don't use if (Balance < withdrawAmount) ?

Comment: And you may want to reconsider your choice in data type to represent an amount.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `-=` to `-`.  `-=` is a distinct binary operator that mutates the value of the first operand by subtracting the amount of the second operand.  If you just want to compare the difference between the two, just use `-`.

Comment: Also, never use float for currencies.  Use `decimal`

Comment: No way lmao my bad. Been looking at this for 2 hours not knowing what the hell i'm doing wrong lol. Thanks i'm still learning so I appretiate your help